# Change structure calendar widget WordPress

Tags: wordpress, calendar, widget

Where do I start if I want to change the placement of the month links in the built-in WordPress calendar from bottom to top?

Do I write some sort of function in functions.php which overrides the basic look of the calendar?

Been Googling like a champ but found nothing (then I maybe not are a champ).

From scratch the month links are placed as this image shows: [image: http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/raw-attachment/ticket/5813/widget-calendar.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by css

```
#wp-calendar{
position:relative;
}
#wp-calendar tfoot td {
position:absolute; 
top:0px; 
}
```